# Is it possible to silently dequeue a request in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

My particular use-case is:
I've got a scraper which is scraping a site, and once an item is yielded - I have a bound signal that sets a key in Redis with an expiration time. The next time the scraper is run, it should ignore all URLs for whom a key exists in Redis.

The first part I have working just fine; the second part - I have created a DownloaderMiddleware which has a `process_request` function which looks at the incoming request object, and checks if its URL exists in Redis. If so, it `raise`s an `IgnoreRequest` exception.

What I would like to know is:
Is there a way to silently dequeue a request instead of raising an exception?
It's not so much a hard requirement as an aesthetic thing; I don't want to see a tonne of these in my error logs - I only want to see bona-fide errors.

I see in the Scrapy source that they're using what looks like a kludge for the duplicate filtering in the main scheduler (scrapy/core/scheduler.py):

```
def enqueue_request(self, request):
    if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
        self.df.log(request, self.spider)
        return False
```

Comment: Can you share what you see in your logs? and what you'd like to have instead? About default duplicate filtering, the default is indeed rather simple, based on [fingerprint of the request (from canonicalized URL, HTTP method, body and headers optionally](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/75cd056223a5a8da87a361aee42a541afcf27553/scrapy/utils/request.py#L19)), but the [dupefilter is customizable](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#std:setting-DUPEFILTER_CLASS). If you have ideas on how to improve or simplify or clarify the design, feel free to open a discussion on Github.

Comment: ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.process_request of <scraper.middlewares.deferred.DeferredURLMiddleware object at 0x1114d5b10>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 26, in send_catch_log
    *arguments, **named)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 57, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File ".../deferred.py", line 22, in process_request
    raise IgnoreRequest('URL is deferred')
IgnoreRequest: URL is deferred

Comment: My middleware looks like this:

`def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.client = Redis()
        self.crawler = crawler

        self.crawler.signals.connect(self.process_request, signals.request_scheduled)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if not self.client.is_deferred(request.url):
            # URL is not deferred, proceed as normal
            return None

        raise IgnoreRequest('URL is deferred')`

Comment: @paultrmbrth I looked at creating a custom dupefilter like you suggested and this worked a treat! Please add that as an answer so I can kick up some votes :) thank you

Comment: another way is to use a spidermiddleware, similar to [deltafetch in scrapylib](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapylib/blob/master/scrapylib/deltafetch.py), skipping requests in `process_spider_output`

Answer (score 3):

Middleware code from OP from comment

```
def __init__(self, crawler):
    self.client = Redis()
    self.crawler = crawler
    self.crawler.signals.connect(self.process_request, signals.request_scheduled)

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    if not self.client.is_deferred(request.url): # URL is not deferred, proceed as normal
        return None
    raise IgnoreRequest('URL is deferred')
```

The problem is with the signal handler you've added on `signals.request_scheduled`. If it raises an exception, [it will appear in the logs](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/utils/signal.py#L36)

I believe it's not correct (or unintential) to register `process_request` as signal handler here.

I'm able to reproduce your console errors with this similar (non-correct) test middleware, which ignore every other request it sees:

```
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

class TestMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        o = cls(crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(o.open_spider, signals.spider_opened)

        # this raises an exception always and will trigger errors in the console
        crawler.signals.connect(o.process, signals.request_scheduled)
        return o

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('TestMiddleware.open_spider()')

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        spider.logger.info('TestMiddleware.process_request()')
        self.counter += 1
        if (self.counter % 2) == 0:
            raise IgnoreRequest("ignoring request %d" % self.counter)

    def process(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Exception
```

See what the console says when running a spider with this middleware:

```
2016-04-06 00:16:58 [scrapy] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.process of <mwtest.middlewares.TestMiddleware object at 0x7f83d4a73f50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy11rc3.py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 30, in send_catch_log
    *arguments, **named)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy11rc3.py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/home/paul/tmp/mwtest/mwtest/middlewares.py", line 26, in process
    raise Exception
Exception
```

The [code is here](https://gist.github.com/redapple/e2b4ac795443de1f611216fa3c4fb681).

Compare with this:

```
$ cat middlewares.py
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

class TestMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        o = cls(crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(o.open_spider, signals.spider_opened)
        return o

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('TestMiddleware.open_spider()')

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        spider.logger.info('TestMiddleware.process_request()')
        self.counter += 1
        if (self.counter % 2) == 0:
            raise IgnoreRequest("ignoring request %d" % self.counter)
```

`IgnoreRequest` is not printed in logs but you have the exception counts in stats at the end:

```
$ scrapy crawl httpbin
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0rc3 started (bot: mwtest)
(...)
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'mwtest.middlewares.TestMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
(...)
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [httpbin] INFO: TestMiddleware.open_spider()
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [httpbin] INFO: TestMiddleware.process_request()
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [httpbin] INFO: TestMiddleware.process_request()
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [httpbin] INFO: TestMiddleware.process_request()
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [httpbin] INFO: TestMiddleware.process_request()
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [httpbin] INFO: TestMiddleware.process_request()
2016-04-06 00:27:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/user-agent> (referer: None)
2016-04-06 00:27:25 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/> (referer: None)
2016-04-06 00:27:25 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/headers> (referer: None)
2016-04-06 00:27:25 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-04-06 00:27:25 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 2,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 2,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 665,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 13006,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 5, 22, 27, 25, 596652),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 13,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 5, 22, 27, 24, 661345)}
2016-04-06 00:27:25 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy uses the Python module `logging` to log things. As what you want is just an aesthetic thing, you could write a [logging filter](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) to filter out what you don't want to see.